# Windows pip3 and python3 disagree

Tags: python, pip

I've been having a problem that python3 from the command line fails to find and import packages installed by pip3 from the command line. Finally I got a clear view of the situation:

```
C:\Users\Ken>where python3
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python3.exe
C:\Users\Ken\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe

C:\Users\Ken>python3 --version
Python 3.10.10

C:\Users\Ken>pip3 --version
pip 23.2.1 from C:\Users\Ken\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

How would python3 and pip3 get out of agreement as to what python version they are talking about?  What's the most graceful way to get them back in order?  I'd rather not break my mingw installation if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

You get around this by directly specifying which python and its specific pip:

```bash
python -m pip

# or
python3 -m pip
```